# What can cause a "Catastrophic failure" error in Delphi IDE

Tags: delphi

I am dead serious about this: I got a "Catastrophic failure" while editing my code in IDE! 
What can cause this? It looks like the error started here: `Forms.TApplication.ActivateHint`

Well, the IDE is working after restart. But I wanted to post it also because it is a bit funny (actually you MUST admit it is quite funny).

```
[5078C302]{xmlrtl150.bpl} XMLDoc.TXMLNode.GetNodeType (Line 2002, "XMLDoc.pas" + 1) + $A
[5078BE61]{xmlrtl150.bpl} XMLDoc.TXMLNode.GetText (Line 1929, "XMLDoc.pas" + 1) + $2
[50799AF9]{xmlrtl150.bpl} XMLIniFile.TXmlIniFile.GetSectionValues (Line 307, "XMLIniFile.pas" + 10) + $1B
[5079949A]{xmlrtl150.bpl} XMLIniFile.TXmlIniFile.ReadSectionValues (Line 177, "XMLIniFile.pas" + 4) + $7
[20A87E57]{coreide150.bpl} PackageList.ClearExistingPackages (Line 298, "PackageList.pas" + 14) + $A
[20A87F6C]{coreide150.bpl} PackageList.TOptionsPackageList.Save (Line 325, "PackageList.pas" + 2) + $4
[21BAD132]{delphicoreide150.bpl} BasePasProjOpts.TProjOptsManager.SaveIDEOptions (Line 1968, "BasePasProjOpts.pas" + 5) + $A
[21BAAA44]{delphicoreide150.bpl} BasePasProjOpts.TProjOptsManager.Save (Line 1232, "BasePasProjOpts.pas" + 16) + $5
[21BADF0F]{delphicoreide150.bpl} BasePasProjOpts.TProjectOptions.Save (Line 2404, "BasePasProjOpts.pas" + 0) + $3
[21B15900]{delphicoreide150.bpl} BaseDelphiProject.TDelphiProjectModuleHandler.SaveFile (Line 2515, "BaseDelphiProject.pas" + 1) + $5
[21B12917]{delphicoreide150.bpl} BaseDelphiProject.TBaseDelphiProject.SaveFile (Line 1380, "BaseDelphiProject.pas" + 24) + $5
[20A7475A]{coreide150.bpl} DocModul.TDocModule.TheMalteseFalcon (Line 1422, "DocModul.pas" + 60) + $6                <----------------- TheMalteseFalcon 
[5013A3F5]{rtl150.bpl  } Rtti.RawInvoke (Line 5538, "Rtti.pas" + 46) + $0
[5013A75A]{rtl150.bpl  } Rtti.Invoke (Line 5729, "Rtti.pas" + 38) + $6
[501335D9]{rtl150.bpl  } Rtti.TRttiInstanceMethodClassic.GetCallingConvention (Line 4103, "Rtti.pas" + 1) + $2
[50133F7F]{rtl150.bpl  } Rtti.TRttiInstanceMethodEx.DispatchInvoke (Line 4408, "Rtti.pas" + 130) + $17
[5013ABC0]{rtl150.bpl  } Rtti.TRttiMethod.Invoke (Line 5859, "Rtti.pas" + 1) + $11
[20A743C6]{coreide150.bpl} DocModul.TDocModule.Save (Line 1346, "DocModul.pas" + 3) + $23
[208440AC]{coreide150.bpl} ProjectModule.TCustomProject.Save (Line 1988, "ProjectModule.pas" + 22) + $9
[20A76546]{coreide150.bpl} DocModul.TCodeIDocModule.Save (Line 2272, "DocModul.pas" + 1) + $2
[20A79425]{coreide150.bpl} DocModul.SaveModifiedModules (Line 3562, "DocModul.pas" + 65) + $20
[20A2D1F1]{coreide150.bpl} DebuggerMgr.TDebuggerMgr.MakeCurrentProject (Line 1267, "DebuggerMgr.pas" + 10) + $15
[20A2EBC9]{coreide150.bpl} DebuggerMgr.TDebuggerMgr.Run (Line 1847, "DebuggerMgr.pas" + 0) + $15
[500AED6F]{rtl150.bpl  } Classes.TBasicAction.Execute (Line 12988, "Classes.pas" + 3) + $7
[5026AA15]{vcl150.bpl  } ActnList.TContainedAction.Execute (Line 448, "ActnList.pas" + 8) + $2C
[5026B7F0]{vcl150.bpl  } ActnList.TCustomAction.Execute (Line 1094, "ActnList.pas" + 7) + $8
[0041A734]{bds.exe     } AppMain.TIDEVCLApplication.ProxyString (Line 7233, "AppMain.pas" + 6) + $C
[0041A1B9]{bds.exe     } AppMain..TDebugXPStyleMenuItem (Line 7099, "AppMain.pas" + 0) + $A0
[209DF4EE]{coreide150.bpl} EditorForm.TEditWindow.CMWindowCommand (Line 3133, "EditorForm.pas" + 14) + $11
[5027DF6C]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7074, "Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[50282830]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 9831, "Controls.pas" + 144) + $6
[5003AEBE]{rtl150.bpl  } System.TMonitor.TryEnter (Line 12708, "System.pas" + 10) + $0
[5003AA38]{rtl150.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Enter (Line 12406, "System.pas" + 4) + $2
[5003A8F0]{rtl150.bpl  } System.TMonitor.CheckOwningThread (Line 12332, "System.pas" + 2) + $0
[5003ABE2]{rtl150.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 12523, "System.pas" + 9) + $7
[5003AC1B]{rtl150.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 12537, "System.pas" + 2) + $7
[50262ECF]{vcl150.bpl  } Graphics.FreeMemoryContexts (Line 7021, "Graphics.pas" + 12) + $8
[50281ED0]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9552, "Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[50281EE5]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9555, "Controls.pas" + 6) + $0
[500AFA64]{rtl150.bpl  } Classes.StdWndProc (Line 13491, "Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[50282830]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 9831, "Controls.pas" + 144) + $6
(0002B8B1){CnWizards_D15.DLL} [099CC8B1]
[5034FB28]{vcl150.bpl  } Forms.TCustomForm.WndProc (Line 3961, "Forms.pas" + 191) + $5
(0002909A){CnWizards_D15.DLL} [099CA09A]
[50281ED0]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9552, "Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[500AFA64]{rtl150.bpl  } Classes.StdWndProc (Line 13491, "Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[50278AA6]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.FindControl (Line 3378, "Controls.pas" + 6) + $9
[50358AF7]{vcl150.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 9760, "Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
[50358B22]{vcl150.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessages (Line 9782, "Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[207B10E4]{coreide150.bpl} ParserThread.TParserTask.WaitFor (Line 217, "ParserThread.pas" + 6) + $7
[50040961]{rtl150.bpl  } System.@IntfCopy (Line 28109, "System.pas" + 6) + $0
[208517CD]{coreide150.bpl} HelpInsight.ShowHelpInsightTip (Line 218, "HelpInsight.pas" + 25) + $C
[21E17D6D]{boreditu.dll} C:\BUILDS\TP\INTERMEDIATE\DEBUG\LIB\UTF8\EK_ENTRY.OBJ.EK_GET_LINE_CONTENTS + $3AD
[209832BA]{coreide150.bpl} EdProcs.SafeEkEval (Line 363, "EdProcs.pas" + 4) + $18
[20981B64]{coreide150.bpl} EdKrnl.EkEval (Line 3557, "EdKrnl.pas" + 2) + $6
[20982B7D]{coreide150.bpl} EdKrnl.LineIsElided (Line 4542, "EdKrnl.pas" + 2) + $1
[20982BD6]{coreide150.bpl} EdKrnl.ElisionLineIncrement (Line 4573, "EdKrnl.pas" + 13) + $F
[209F7B06]{coreide150.bpl} EditorControl.TCustomEditControl.LineFromY (Line 4983, "EditorControl.pas" + 5) + $1
[209F157C]{coreide150.bpl} EditorControl.TCustomEditControl.CheckHelpInsight (Line 1751, "EditorControl.pas" + 8) + $17
[209FEC2D]{coreide150.bpl} EditorControl.TEditEventHandler.FormHintShow (Line 8416, "EditorControl.pas" + 72) + $11
[209F1D55]{coreide150.bpl} EditorControl.TCustomEditControl.CMHintShow (Line 1992, "EditorControl.pas" + 4) + $2
[5027DF6C]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7074, "Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
(0002B799){CnWizards_D15.DLL} [099CC799]
(0002B800){CnWizards_D15.DLL} [099CC800]
(0002B8B1){CnWizards_D15.DLL} [099CC8B1]
[50282830]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 9831, "Controls.pas" + 144) + $6
[5027DB90]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TControl.Perform (Line 6852, "Controls.pas" + 10) + $8
[5035A2EE]{vcl150.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.ActivateHint (Line 10776, "Forms.pas" + 35) + $10
[50359DC1]{vcl150.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.HintTimerExpired (Line 10561, "Forms.pas" + 8) + $4
[50356A32]{vcl150.bpl  } Forms.HintTimerProc (Line 8330, "Forms.pas" + 3) + $5
[50358AF7]{vcl150.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 9760, "Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
[50358B3A]{vcl150.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 9790, "Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[50358E65]{vcl150.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 9927, "Forms.pas" + 26) + $3
```

Comment: If necessary I can also post a screenshot of the 'catastrophic' error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an IDE bug. There are plenty of them. There's not very much that you can do about it. And it could be a problem either with Delphi or with a plugin.

You are running XE, and there will be no more updates to XE. You could try Andy Hausladen's IDE FixPack. That might help. You could perhaps see if you can isolate a reproduction of the fault, and then find a way to work around it.

Comment: ...might also suspect a bug in CnWizards?

Comment: Hi David. I should do some research to see if it worth upgrading to Delphi XE5. With their prices I can only afford to upgrade if they added A LOT of goodies. They oriented to multi-platform but I am not interested in that.

Comment: Well, that has plenty of bugs. I'd let functionality drive upgrades. For me it was Unicode and 64 bit.

Comment: Anybody knows if there a document like "What's new in Delphi since Delphi XE?". Found it: http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/whats-new